# Is it possible to make `xrdb` ignore single quotes on a commented line?

Tags: rxvt, x-resources

I'm using `rxvt-unicode`, version `9.22`, as a terminal emulator, and configure it with the file `~/.Xresources`.

When I modify the configuration file, to see the effects immediately I execute the command:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

From `man xrdb`:

> Lines that begin with an exclamation mark (!) are ignored and may be used as comments.

On my machine, with `xrdb` version `1.1.0`, when a commented line contains an odd number of single quotes, for example `! it's a comment`, `xrdb` complains with an error such as:

```
/home/user/.Xresources:1:5: warning: missing terminating ' character
 ! it's a comment
     ^
```

Currently, I double the single quotes to avoid this error:

```
! it''s a comment
```

I think I could also use `/* */`, instead of `!`, because it's the comment string used by default by Vim (defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/xdefaults.vim`). But I would prefer using `!`, because I find comments a little more readable with it.

Is there a way to ask `xrdb` to ignore single quotes inside the commented lines of `~/.Xresources`?

Comment: xrdb is using the C preprocessor, which is (a) why it complains about quotes and (b) recognizes C-style comments.

Comment: This seems to be due to a change in the default behavior of GNU `cpp`. See [The C Preprocessor: 10.1 Traditional lexical analysis](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-lexical-analysis.html#Traditional-lexical-analysis). At least on my current system (Ubuntu 16.10) the warning goes away if you use `xrdb -cpp "/usr/bin/cpp -traditional-cpp"` or `xrdb -cpp "/usr/bin/cpp -traditional"` explicitly.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you very much for the explanation. @steeldriver Thank you, your command works on my system too (Ubuntu 16.04). I could create an alias for it, for an interactive use. However, I don't know what happens at boot time. When the X session starts, should I configure something so that `~/.Xresources` is read with `xrdb` using the option `-cpp`? Anyway, the command works, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be due to a change in the default behavior of GNU `cpp`, which `xrdb` uses as its default preprocessor. Specifically, according to [The C Preprocessor: 10.1 Traditional lexical analysis](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-lexical-analysis.html#Traditional-lexical-analysis):

> Generally speaking, in traditional mode an opening quote need not have
>   a matching closing quote.

However `cpp` provides a command line option to operate in traditional mode:

```
-traditional
-traditional-cpp
    Try to imitate the behavior of pre-standard C preprocessors, as opposed to ISO 
    C preprocessors. See Traditional Mode.
```

while `xrdb` allows the preprocessor to be defined explicitly on its command line:

```
-cpp filename
       This  option  specifies the pathname of the C preprocessor pro‐
       gram to be used.  Although xrdb was designed to  use  CPP,  any
       program  that  acts  as a filter and accepts the -D, -I, and -U
       options may be used.
```

Hence it should be possible to suppress the warning by using

```
xrdb -cpp "/usr/bin/cpp -traditional-cpp"  ~/.Xresources
```

or

```
xrdb -cpp "/usr/bin/cpp -traditional"  ~/.Xresources
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the error by replacing single quotes (') with Unicode apostrophes (’) in .Xresources comments.

There are [other](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html) Unicode options, if the apostrophe doesn't suit you.